# Find and change materialize generated html elements from react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, materialize

In a couple of places of my app, I have some code I am not very proud of. I need to find some elements that are handled by [materialize](https://materializecss.com/) to manipulate them, so that they are displayed according to my needs.
So I do this two things in two different parts of my code:

```
// 1.- set style from grey (placeholder text) to black(input text) and erase placeholder only on 1rst  option select
const dropdownWrapper = document.getElementsByClassName('select-dropdown dropdown-trigger')[0];
dropdownWrapper.setAttribute("style", "color:black;");

// 2.- remove AM PM labels from display
let ampmLabels = document.getElementsByClassName('timepicker-span-am-pm')[0];
ampmLabels.setAttribute("style", "display:none;");
```

I don't consider useRef because the elements are not part of any specific component. They are in the DOM put there by materialize when I initialize the materialize element in my component and I manipulate them from that component to fit my needs when they're displayed.

As I know there are no more elements of this type when I run de code, the `document.getElementsByClassName('select-dropdown dropdown-trigger')[0];` works, but isn't there a more elegant way to find a manipulate dom elements to do this?

Edit:

The componenet where the color cannot be changed is an input type with a `type="text"` attribute:

html with `dropdownWrapper.classList.add('text-black');`:

```
<input class="select-dropdown dropdown-trigger text-black" type="text" readonly="true" data-target="select-options-ee9a6017-aef6-ecbf-c2a1-298693b77804">
```

html with `dropdownWrapper.setAttribute("style", "color:black;");`:

```
<input class="select-dropdown dropdown-trigger" type="text" readonly="true" data-target="select-options-ee9a6017-aef6-ecbf-c2a1-298693b77804" style="color: black;">
```

Seems that because of that the `dropdownWrapper.classList.add('text-black');` does not work. This adds the `text black` to the class name in the `class="select-dropdown dropdown-trigger text-black"` (note the `text-black` at the end) but does not change the text color even if the `.text-black {color: black}` is added to the css file.

The style change with `setAttribute`, produces the `style="color: black;"` at the end of the html that is what seems what is actually changing the color.

Comment: "I manipulate them from my component" - from a React component, you're manipulating DOM that's outside of it? That sounds pretty evil

Comment: Are you sure there will only be 1 element macting the class names?

Comment: from a React component, you're manipulating DOM that's outside of it? The elements are inside the component hierarchy in the DOM, but not in the component's code. They are injected in the hierarchy when I initialize my materialize element, for example a [time picker](https://materializecss.com/pickers.html). So I need to look it up in the dom if I need to do any change. Hop that makes sense :)

Comment: Are you sure there will only be 1 element macting the class names? Yea because I initialize them myself. As the app is not very complicated and I checked that, I know it and it works. However, its pretty evil :)

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to do this through JavaScript? Why not override the CSS style?

Comment: the css code is from materialize, so I think I cannot handle that directly. The way the css is overriden as per suggested in the answer seems to be the way: `addClass('.timepicker-span-am-pm', 'hidden');` is there any other? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
function addClass(selector, className) {
  const element = document.querySelector(selector);
  element.classList.add(className);
}

/* maybe move these strings to constants, add comments*/
addClass('.select-dropdown.dropdown-trigger', 'text-black');
addClass('.timepicker-span-am-pm', 'hidden');
```

---

Tiny improvements:

- You can use [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)
- You can also add the styles in a CSS class and use [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) API:

Long version:

```
const dropdownWrapper = document.querySelector('.select-dropdown.dropdown-trigger');
dropdownWrapper.classList.add('text-black');

const ampmLabels = document.querySelector('.timepicker-span-am-pm');
ampmLabels.classList.add('hidden');
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer, with `classList.add('hidden');` the element hides, but with `classList.add('text-black');` the text does not turn to black. Any tips on how that can be done with your useful tips? thanks

Comment: `'color:black;'` with your suggestion `dropdownWrapper.classList.add('color:black');` is not changing the color to black neither. The dropdownWrapper is being obtained correctly from the DOM, meaning it is not null. Any suggestion? thanks

Comment: You need to implement those classes in a CSS file and import them. It looks like a library or something you're using already contains the `hidden` class (It's a standared name for class containing `display : none`). You need to define `.text-black {color: black}` in CSS file/ or `<style></style>` tag

Comment: it still does not change the text color, it just adds the `text-black` to the style name. I edited the question and posted the code. The html element is: `type="text"`. Does that make any difference?

Comment: by  "it just adds the text-black to the style name" I was meaning to the class name.

Comment: @rustyBucketBay sounds like the default colors from library have high specificity. What if you make your css file like `.select-dropdown.dropdown-trigger.text-black { color: black}` ?